# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am searching to do a program for fun but i have some problems with selenium and i 
need some help...
This is the programm (i deleted the directory of webdriver because the folder's name contain the name of an other person)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import time


def Pass_send_():
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('chrome://flags/#password_export-enable')


    ricerca=driver.find_element_by_id("search")
    ricerca.send_keys('password export')
    scorritore=driver.find_element_by_class_name('experiment-select')
    scorritore.click()



Pass_send_()
```

And so the purpose it's easy, it should open a windows, type a text and click a button. everything works but the click doesn't and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\internet22.py", line 18, in <module>
Pass_send_()
  File "C:\Python34\internet22.py", line 14, in Pass_send_
scorritore.click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
   packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

So i am not an expert but it says: element not intercatable? what does it mean and how can i fix it? i would really appreciate a reply...

Comment: You can add some time.sleep() after you send search keys. As the api may take time to load, so if you can have 5 sec delay, it will help you solve this problem.

Comment: well i tried but it didn't work, however i understood a new powerfull function so thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *search box* within the webpage `chrome://flags/#password_export-enable` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('chrome://flags/#password_export-enable')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search"))).send_keys("password export")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: chrome_password_export]

Comment: So the error is gone but it doesn't works.... it opens the page and type the text but it doesn't click the button

Comment: i think because  with your code the programm wait untill te button is clickable but for a reason, that i don't know, it isn't clickable so the program contiunue to wait...

Comment: @ScooterzGiovanni As per your question the step _...type a text..._ was clear that you want to send a _character sequence_ to the **search box**, you never told us about which _...click a button..._. As per your code trial, `find_element_by_class_name('experiment-select')` identifies **690** elements.