# How to click on this button with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here are all the parts of the element I am trying to click according to 'Inspect':

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    ::before
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button type="button" class="done ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">
        Done</button>
    </div>
    ::after
</div>
```

When I want to click it, I assume it is on the `::before` part as it is showing and clickable. In the code, I make sure to scroll and wait two seconds before clicking to make sure that the button is visible and yet I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

But I don't understand how it's not interactable. When I hover over it in the inspector, everything in `<button>...</button>` highlights, so the button I want to click must be in there, right?

Here are few things that I have tried:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=button]').click()

browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Done')]").click()

# The above returns a list for some reason?

browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('done.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget')
```

I wish I could remember all that I tried, but regardless I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Show ur source page if possible, otherwise others can not debug to help. In addition, selenium can execute script, u can try javascript or jquery script to make element interactable or even do all the steps with them.

Comment: When you use `.find_elements` (note the plural) it will return a list instead of a single element like `.find_element` (singular) does. Have you tried `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Done']")`? If you get a `len()` on these `.find_elements` calls... is it 1? I'm wondering if there isn't more than one button that matches the locators you are using and the first isn't visible but you want the second or third, etc.

Comment: @JeffC Jeff my friend, you are literally my hero. I clicked a specific element withIN that list, and it worked wonderfully. Answer the question with this so that you I can give you a check mark for giving me the answer. You deserve everything.

Comment: @jeepersmcface , note that in case of `ElementNotVisibleException` this approach (using `find_elements_..`) should be only used to check number of elements matched by selector, but not to select required element by index. You should still search for unique selector.

Comment: Agree with @Andersson. I'm guessing there are multiple buttons in the table, each on a different row. You should be able to construct an XPath for a given button based on a value in the table. That's the better way to do this... my comment that turned into an answer was more of a debugging step. Well it doesn't have to be a row in a table, that's just an example...

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element as the desired element is a *dynamic* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469689/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotvisibleexception-message-element-not-inte/53469899#53469899)

Comment: Hm... I get selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.find_elements` (note the plural) it will return a list instead of a single element like `.find_element` (singular) does. Have you tried

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Done']")
```

If you get a `len()` on these `.find_elements` calls... is it 1? I'm wondering if there isn't more than one button that matches the locators you are using and the first isn't visible but you want the second or third, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ActionChains to move to element

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

or u can scroll till element is in view using scrollIntoView():

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```